# Is there any way to bookmark a Django "current" documentation page, without version numbers?

Tags: django, documentation

The point of this is to keep notes/urls pointing to particular parts of the documentation that people want to refer to in the future.  For example, when something is a complex feature that requires a little bit of review most of the times you work with it.

---

Let's take an example.  I search for Django STATICFILES_DIR:

https://www.google.com/search?q=django+STATICFILES_DIRS

Pretty quickly I get exactly what I want:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

which has a STATICFILES_DIR configuration entry.

**But,  notice from the url, this is for Django `4.1`.  And it says so on the page too.**

[image]

But maybe there are a *current* version?  Let's look.

There isn't.

[image]

Contrast with Python, which points to a very generic, `3` version.  Not to Python `3.10` or `3.11`.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Or postgres (looking for create table):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html

OK, yes, I have a version 14, but...

[image]

I can click on that *current* and that will **NOT** pin me to a particular version.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

In the case of Django, Python and Postgresql, I am pretty confident a generic, version-less documentation page will serve my purposes just fine 90% of the time - those are pretty stable APIs by now.

Often searching gets you to ancient postgresql versions like 9.2, but you can always find a *current* link.

Am I looking in the wrong places for a permanent link for Django docs?

Yes, there is `dev` link on the Django versions, but that's living a bit dangerously, I assume people are potentially working updating the docs on the current version on that URL.  Or should I use that after all?

Comment: I don't think there is one. But, I would love to know why someone would need such URLs?

Comment: Because I bookmark things in **pinboard** and annotate some urls with tags and notes specific to my work.  Why do you think postgresql and others have their scheme to track current version?  Because many people don’t want to link their notes to multiple different versions of the same software.  You may not find it valuable, others might.

Comment: TBH, I don't know how Django (team/board) reached that decision, maybe most people may not see this feature as beneficial, or even they may not think about it.

Comment: To me, `dev/develop` and `stable/current` doesn't really matter (in the case of bookmark) since after a certain time those contents can be changed.

Comment: I want to link to the Django tutorial in general. There is no URL for that. Only versioned ones.

Answer (score 0):

Going to use the `dev` tag for now.  Django is stable enough that I expect minimal problems there and I can always go back to my version of interest from there.  But at least I don't have bookmarks pointing to a bunch of different historical versions.